# my sql error #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Tags: mysql, database

I created an event that update a table every 3 min and it work perfectly offline on my local machine (xammpp) but when i try to import that code it keep showing me this error

> my sql error #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

this is the code i was trying

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `onlineoff` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 MINUTE 
    STARTS '2021-11-06 13:19:59' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
        DO UPDATE users set online='false'
```

i also try this

```
CREATE DEFINER=`uqzqyahdcxqda`@`localhost` EVENT `onlineoff` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 MINUTE 
    STARTS '2021-11-06 13:19:59' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
        DO UPDATE users set online='false'
```

but it didnt work

Comment: The error says it all.. Mysql User permissions need to be adjusted

Comment: You will not have access to the `root` on a shared server! And the account you do have access with has deliberately been limited so you dont naff up someone else on a MySQL server shared by potentially 1000's of other sites